# PDF text changes case when copied to Notepad

Tags: pdf, copy-paste, notepad

For example.

In PDF it's **The** but when I copy to notepad it pastes **the** . How to copy text with same case?

**for example:** ("the" is just for example)

This is PDF

```
The Superman xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx x xxxx xx
xxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxxx x to you x x xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx
xxxx xxxxxx
The xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx x xxxx xx
xxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxxx x x xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx
xxxx xxxxxx
```

This is pasted text (see " of second paragrapht")

```
The Superman xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx x xxxx xx
xxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxxx x to you x x xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx
xxxx xxxxxx
the xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx x xxxx xx
xxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxxx x x xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx
xxxx xxxxxx
```

Comment: You think that's bad... see  http://superuser.com/questions/119393/search-pdfs-with-non-standard-character-encodings  BTW what file are you looking at? Is it publicly available?

Comment: On a Mac, I can hardly select any text from that example in Apple's Preview. In Adobe Reader on a Mac, it [doesn't even display correctly](http://img.skitch.com/20100405-qup58p32aig7ukur8jrp8qh5f6.png)...

Comment: it's okay PDF has 3 word only. problem is with copy and paste in notepad. i cropped PDF due to copyright. I'm on windows XP.

Comment: your screenshot is right. on windows Xp's adobe reader it's also looking same.

Comment: yes it's happening with some letters. at many places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing the example into [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/), selecting "Import text as text" gives me a lowercase "the" as well. The same is true for the first letter of all other sentences.

It also shows some odd spacing after those letters. That same odd spacing is present after the first letters in other text fragments, like after the first letters in some list of 4 items in the second column. These letters indeed also show as lowercase in Inkscape, but are uppercased in a normal PDF view.

[image: Lowercase first character for each sentence]

The document properties show that the PDF was created using "Adobe Acrobat 8.1 Combine Files". I guess that application linked something like [small capitals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps) from an imported document to normal looking uppercase vector shapes?

In general, some other options:

- If the PDF is a scanned document, then some scan software not only includes the scanned image (which is what you see), but also performs [OCR](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) to include hidden text in the same document (which is what you search and copy). But often this OCR is not perfect. To get better results, OCR often uses a spell checking dictionary as well<sup>†</sup>.

  It's hard to imagine that OCR would mistake `T` for `t`, but if it interpreted the `T` as an `I` (uppercase i) then maybe after that a spell checker changed `Ihe` into `the`.
- If it's not a scanned document, then maybe the source document used small capitals for the formatting? I'm not sure if PDF supports that, but then the plain text (without any formatting) might indeed be "the", not "The".

<sup>†</sup> As a result, OCR can sometimes fix errors that are actually present in the original text.

Comment: @Arjan - see added example

Comment: @Arjan - see my comment under question

Comment: So now what is the best quickest option to correct all instances in long PDF. I have to use this document to make HTML version. is the manual case correction for each instances ,the only way?

Comment: @Metal, any idea how that PDF was created then? I guess it better be fixed in the source. Or maybe the source used some font for those first characters that was not available on the computer that created the final PDF? Then maybe installing the font prior to generating the PDF helps.