# Cut-paste produces squares from a PDF created with GNU Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript, postscript, cut-and-paste

A [PDF from the net](http://www.biu.ac.il/SOC/besa/docs/perspectives78.pdf) looks fine in Chrome or PDF reader/editor, viz:

[image: pdf page in chrome]

However, if I try to `copy-paste` that page, either to MS word or a text editor, this is what I get:

[image: result of cut-paste]

I tried the suggestions of [PDF has garbled text when copy pasting](https://superuser.com/questions/137824/pdf-has-garbled-text-when-copy-pasting), https://forums.adobe.com/thread/427945?start=0&tstart=0, [PDF has garbled text when copy pasting](https://superuser.com/questions/137824/pdf-has-garbled-text-when-copy-pasting), and virtually all the results of https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=solved+pdf+cut+and+paste+shows+as+squars, but none worked.

Opening [the PDF](http://www.biu.ac.il/SOC/besa/docs/perspectives78.pdf) in (Foxit Fantom) PDF editor, I get the following information on [the PDF document](http://www.biu.ac.il/SOC/besa/docs/perspectives78.pdf):

[image: fonts embedded in PDF]

[image: PDF description]

**Can anything be done to the PDF to make cut-paste work as expected?**

Comment: Just a quick look reveals that none of the fonts have an encoding entry, and the Times Roman font is not embedded at all. The not having an encoding entry looks to me as the culprit for not being able to show their characters.

Comment: Thanks @Max. Can something be done to enable cut-paste to work, bearing in mind that these characters *do* show in PDF readers?

Comment: Not really; get after the creator of the PDFs and "persuade" them to create proper PDFs. OK, there may be a possibility, but it is a bit a kludge: Create a TIFF from the PDF pages, re-open them in Acrobat and run OCR over it. That should then lead to the proper encoding…