# How can I copy this quote from PDF?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, copy-paste

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDF has garbled text when copy pasting](https://superuser.com/questions/137824/pdf-has-garbled-text-when-copy-pasting)

I'm reading a [PDF copy](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/dm-stat.pdf) of Jerome H. Friedman's paper "Data Mining and Statistics: What's the Connection?" using Google Chrome.

It contains an amusing quote that I want to copy and paste to my blog.

I used the mouse to select the text of the quote and pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the text. The document looks like this:

[image: A highlighted quote from Jerome's paper.]

When I paste the text into Notepad, Stack Overflow, or anywhere else, the product is Wingdings-like gibberish:

> ➣✍❺❼⑤➭✸❸❊➁❥❸❊⑥▼❽❾❸✘➎✳❸❾②❘➊➥❸❊❸❊⑥❦⑨❘②③✇▲➆
>   ②❥⑤⑩⑨❘②❥⑤⑩❽❾⑤⑩✇➄⑥▼⑨❏✇➄⑥▼❺➌❽❾❻➀➍♣➂⑦❶❼②❥❸❊➁❷⑨❥❽❾⑤❸❊⑥✗②❥⑤⑩⑨❘②③⑨✘⑤⑥☎②❥➇⑦⑤⑩⑨ ➔❸❊➅⑩❺➌⑨❹❸❊❸❊➍P⑨①②❥❻
>   ➎✳❸❏②❥➇▼✇▲②➟➊❚➇⑦❸❊⑥✆✇P⑨❘②③✇▲②❥⑤⑩⑨❘②❥⑤⑩❽❾⑤⑩✇➄⑥❦➇▼✇➀⑨↔✇➄⑥❦⑤⑩❺❼❸✶✇♣➇⑦❸❷❻➀➁↔⑨❹➇⑦❸❷➊❚➁❥⑤②❥❸✶⑨
>   ✇❨➂▼✇➄➂✳❸❊➁✶Þ⑦✇♣❽❾❻➀➍♣➂⑦❶❼②❥❸❊➁➟⑨❥❽❾⑤❸❊⑥✗②❥⑤⑩⑨❘②↔⑨❘②③✇➄➁❹②③⑨❚✇♣❽❾❻➀➍♣➂▼✇➄⑥☛➧➀➏

The text should instead look like this:

> A difference between statisticians and computer scientists in this field seems to be that when a statistician has an idea he or she writes a paper; a computer scientist starts a company.

I had to type that text out manually. This is feasible for such a small quote, but how do I actually copy what I see?

Is it something unusual about the PDF, the browser, the plugin, or some combiniation of the three?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most reliable way of doing it is by using OCR.

But as a dirty and fast solution you can use Google [**Quick View**](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:TqtsAhuubD4J:www-stat.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/dm-stat.pdf+&hl=en&gl=uk&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShQbK3xrlEbAzT0VM7Psz49QnVrMxFGq9ypry4cbFPPqfIy6hsryHKLVjTQ661YI6l5JlVAcRSibX9RkQFO13aFiURM6XgxY5nuzU3KKsUp8H8FGXAz0sbf9g8weeJtkstBO2U_&sig=AHIEtbQdVswrbSmKn5WwV9KAMrDtvGki0w&pli=1) from the [search result](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_nf=1&tok=M8KaVuIXrWauOrp2SK880Q&cp=49&gs_id=4&xhr=t&q=http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/dm-stat.pdf&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/dm-stat.pdf&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=71c328421847cc95&biw=942&bih=917) for your link, in Quick view use option **View > Plain HTML**.

It still contains some garbled text and is quite **unreadable** but a large amount of text is correct and  **copy-able**. Search works here so you can use it to locate the target text and copy it without any garbled text.

---

**Detailed Example here:**
[image: Google search results for URL includes Quick View link.]

---

Then use View option **Plain HTML**.

---

[image: The Quick View has an options to view the document as HTML.]

---

On Google's [HTML version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:TqtsAhuubD4J:www-stat.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/dm-stat.pdf+&hl=en&gl=uk), you can search and select the equivalent text like this:

---

[image: Search the HTML verion to find and select the relevant quote.]

---

Pasting into Notepad produces this output:

> A difference between sta-tisticians and computer scientists in this field seems tobe that when a statistician has an idea he or she writesa paper; a computer scientist starts a company.

Not exactly as displayed, but close enough that you can work with it.

Comment: I forgot that Google cached PDFs that way! Very useful. I edited your answser to include a step-by-step guide with pictures to make this answer more generally useful.

Comment: In the Google Search version that Google serves to my machine, Instead of having this "Quick View" link, I have to click the down arrow, then choose "Cached". But that works too.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to discard the corrupted text that's already associated with the PDF before you can re-OCR it.  The easiest way to do that is to save it in TIFF format, then open it with Acrobat and re-OCR it.  When I did that, it worked for me.

Comment: I can't verify this solution because I don't have Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: I've re-OCRed it for you with Acrobat X and uploaded it to a free site at http://pdfcast.org/pdf/data-mining-and-statistics-what-s-the-connection  The OCR isn't (by any means!) perfect, but hopefully will be usable.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a PDF with incorrect encoding. See the following threads:

- [Copy text from a PDF to word. Just get Symbols](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/427945)
- [PDF has garbled text when copy pasting](https://superuser.com/questions/137824/pdf-has-garbled-text-when-copy-pasting)
- [search PDFs with non-standard character encodings](https://superuser.com/questions/119393/search-pdfs-with-non-standard-character-encodings)

Try printing the PDF using [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/CutePDF/writer.asp), then see if the resulting PDF is any better.