# Cant copy source code from pdf files in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pdf

How to copy source code from pdf files in ubuntu. No tabs are copied at the beginning of lines. I have tried many pdf viewers: evince, Adobe Reader, xpdf. Is there any solution for it ?

Comment: It could be a restriction in the PDF file.

Comment: I can normally copy from the same file on windows.

Comment: This might help http://superuser.com/questions/481493/how-can-i-copy-this-quote-from-pdf/481510#481510